# Parallel Producers in Disruptor (Ring buffer) (used in log4j2)

Tags: java, log4j2, disruptor-pattern

So I understand the purpose of the LMX Disruptor algorithm (used in log4j2). My question is why can’t producers just write to multiple slots in the ring buffer in parallel. Why do we need a write pointer, since next sequence generator is assigning incrementing numbers to different processes. I understand that serialising writes (and write pointers), helps consumers to know up to which slot can be read. Is that the only reason?

Answer (score 0):

How would you prevent multiple producers from writing into the same slot?

Asuming you are using the `MultiProducerSequencer`, a single producer can write into multiple slots by calling `next(int)` and multiple parallel producers can obviously write into slots in parallel either in single slots (`next()`) or batches (`next(int)`).

Comment: The next sequence generator would have a CAS right? (lightweight lock)? So even in case of multiple producers all of them would have different sequence numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are getting at.  What do you mean by "the next sequence generator" and how does that differ to the `cursor` used in `MultiProducerSequencer`?  What do are you referring to when you mention a "write pointer"